# Restriction of SAT to CNF

Tags: np-complete, polynomial-time-reductions

I have spent a lot of time understanding these two issues. If you can help me, please.

1. Prove that the restriction of SAT to CNF formulas in which each variable xi appears at most twice is solvable in polynomial time.
2. Prove that the restriction of SAT to CNF formulas in which each variable xi appears
   at most three times is NP-complete by showing $SAT \leqslant_p SAT_3 $ 
   (hint: find a way to
   create “clones” of each variable with different names.)

Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: For the first problem I thought of this idea,  Consider a variable xi. If it appears once, or if it appears twice but in the same polarity (i.e., both times as a positive literal or both times as a negative literal), then we can set it accordingly and satisfy all the clauses that contain it (more formally, any satisfying assignment can be converted into a satisfying assignment in which xi has this value).

Comment: But for the second problem I don't really know how we do it, if you have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can apply [Davis-Putnam procedure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157704/652298) and note that with the given restriction applying resolution rule will not be increasing formula size exponentially (in fact, it will be decreasing it). Thus, every iteration of procedure will have polynomial time complexity.
2. Read about [Tseytin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) and try to exploit the same idea. You can replace variable $x$ with $y$ and add $x \leftrightarrow y$ to the formula. With a proper replacement strategy you will be able to obtain an equisatisfiable formula in which every variable occurs at most three times: one in the original formula, one as the left part of equivalence, one as the right one.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm doing well with the Davis-puttan procedure. But I didn't quite understand the transformation of tseytin. Can you give an example on a formula $phi$ in CNF please